# Angular Material UI Dialog suddenly becomes transparent

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material

Angular Material UI Dialog's background became transparent from today.
Upon checking, it is identified, if I explicitly provide `background-color: white` css to the class `mat-dialog-container`, then it works as before. But for this, I need to apply the CSS for all the Dialogs.

Initially it was working perfectly fine without adding of this CSS.
[image: Initial working witout CSS & now when expilictly CSS is provided]
[image: Without Adding the CSS as per now]

Wanted to know whether this is a change from the Library's end? And will it be fixed soon?
Since my application is running into Production since months, and suddenly from today morning it started breaking.

Angular version: 9
Material UI Version: "^9.1.1"

Sample HTML code:

```
<ng-template
  #priceChangeDialog>

  <mat-dialog-content>
    <p>Here is the content</p>
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="btn btn-info mr-2" [matDialogClose]="{confirmChange: false}">
        Cancel
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-info">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</ng-template>
```

Component file code:

```
const dialogRef = this.confirmDialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      data: {
        template
      }
    });
```

Generic DialogComponent:

```
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
      public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData,
              public router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

That Generic Component's HTML file:

```
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="data.template"></ng-template>
```

Comment: can you please create simple demo on stackblitz ? it's hard to detect problem from screenshot

Comment: It's worth creating a minimal reproducible example (MRE) of the issue & sharing the code for that, and also saying what version of the package you're on to help others reproduce and understand your issue.

Comment: Angular version is 9, and the version for the material - `@angular/material` is `9.1.1`.

Comment: For the stackblitz demo, please give me some time

Comment: I tried to update the Description with some sample code - can you please help me - if you can?